# HTML Table and JavaScript addRows and addColumns without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm having a problem getting the buttons on my student grades table working, I have a button to calculate the average of the grades using a function called getAverage(), I have one to insert rows to the table using a function called insert_Rows, and finally one to add columns using a function called insert_Column().

My problem is that none of them seem to be working and I can't see why the getAverage function was working until I added the other two buttons.

This is for an assignment where I'm not allowed to use jQuery.

Also, this is the brief for the two buttons:

1. A CSS styled button that inserts a new table row suitable for recording new student data. You can insert after the last row of the table. Students should provide on button that saves the table in its current state i.e. if there are 5 rows and 6 cells, the cookie should reflect that.
2. A CSS style button that inserts a new table column suitable for recording new Assignment grade data. This column requires a title. You can decide how you wish to accomplish the title allocation (automatic, content-edit, etc.). There should be another button that then retrieves that data and fills it back to the table in the state that it previously held. If extra rows or columns have been added, the table should revert back to its previous state when the cookie was saved (5 rows and 6 cells).

Also, for extra credit, I have to use JavaScript and any method of my choosing to delete a data row selected by a user, and another on to delete an assignment column selected by the user, the function should ensure that the final grade column totals are updated following this deletion.

```
// get the average
function getAverage()
{
    let table = document.getElementById("gradesTable");  
    //Loop over the rows array directly
  let rows = Array.prtotype.slice.call(table.rows); //let is block scoped - can only be used in this block
  rows.froEach(function(row)
  {
    let cells = array.protoype.slice.call(row.querySelectorAll(".Assignment")); // Get all the Assignment cells into an array

    // declairing sum and gradeAverage with let and by defining them in the row loop keeps the values unique for each row
    let sum = 0; 
    let gradeAverage = 0;

    // Now just loop the cells Array
    cells.forEach(function(cell,index){

     //.textContent instead for strings that dont contain any values
      var currentValue = parseInt(cell.textContent);
      if(currentValue >= 0 && currentValue <=100){
          sum += currentValue;
      }

      // If the cell has "-" for content
      if(cell.textContent === '"-"'){
        // Apply a pre-made CSS class
        cell.classList.add("noGrade");
      } else {
        // Remove a pre-made CSS class
        cell.classList.remove("noGrade");
      }

      // If this is the last cell in the row
      if(index === cells.length-1){
        gradeAverage = sum/5;
        cell.nextElementSibling.textContent = Math.round(gradeAverage) + "%";

        // There is a grade, so check it for low
        if(gradeAverage >= 0 && gradeAverage < 40) {
          cell.nextElementSibling.classList.add("lowGrade");
        } else {
          cell.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("lowGrade");
        }
      }

    });
  });

}

// add a row to the table
function insert_Row() {
  let table = document.getElementById("gradesTable"); //assign table id to a variable
  let tableRows = table.rows.length; // gives how many rows in the table
  let row = table.insertRow(tableRows); //insert after the last row in the table
  let cellsInTable = document.getElementById("gradesTable").rows[0].cells 
  let columnTotal = cellsInTable.length; //assign the columnTotal the number of columns that the first row has

  //loop through each column
  for(let i = 0; i < columnTotal; i++)
  {
    //add a new cell for each column
    let cell = row.insertCell(i);

    //assign each new cell the default value "-"
    cell.innerHTML = "-";


  }

}

// add a column to the HTML table
function appendColumn() 
{
    let table = document.getElementById("gradesTable"); // table reference

    // open loop for each row and append cell
    for(let x = 0; x < table.rows.length; x++)
    {
        createCell(tbale.rows[x].insertCell(table.rows[x].cells.lenght), x, "col");
    }      
}


function insert_Column()
{

}
function deleteColumn()
{
    let allRows = document.getElementById("gradesTable").rows;
    for (var i=0; i < allRows.length; i++) 
  {
        if (allRows[i].cells.length > 1) 
    {
            allRows[i].deleteCell(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Correction, the Insert row function seems to be working right, but the grades average function isn't and I don't know where to begin writing the other functions.

If anyone can offer advice or best places to learn? Because my lecturer has just informed us to use W3Schools and he's not teaching us the language, I just feel out of my depth.

Comment: `let cells = array.protoype.slice.call(...` You want `Array` not `array`; JavaScript is case-sensitive. Or just use `Array.from(...)`. You should be getting an error on that in your console though...

Comment: Thank you I fixed that, but oddly enough it wasn’t preventing my insert_Row function from working

Comment: I would highly suggest learning about the JavaScript debugger in your browser of choice. Then you can see exactly what's happening in each line of your code.

Comment: +1, You have a lot of straight typos in the above code that would be immediately obvious in the errors that chrome devtools shows you.